# How to connect 2 3v3 lines in parallel from different dc/dc converters?

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter

Is there any way, to connect 2 different (but same output voltage) dc/dc converters? One of them works on 5 to 40 Volts, and one on 3 to 5.

Comment: To what end? (i.e., for what purpose)

Comment: 3v3 is needed for the MCU (and peripherials), and it has to be able to operate from battery (4.5V) and from electric cigar-lighter (12-24V)

Comment: The 12-24V source would be used, when the battery is drained down. On the lower voltage dc/dc conv. theres and enable pin, if I were to connect the 12-24V dc/dc conv. output to the enable (matching high-low), it would basically disable the other IC, but I'm not sure whether or not it would mess up the hole power line.

Comment: Make the outputs of each DC-DC 3.5V and use a schottky (rectifier) diode on each supply's output to isolate them from one another.

Comment: How much current is your circuit using?

Comment: Under 200 mA, typically less than 100 mA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application can tolerate a small resistance in the power circuit then Voltage Regulators with same output voltage can be paralleled easily.

Consider the circuit below where V1 and V2 are nominally 1V but in reality may be a little different. Then with zero load (I1=0): \$I_{R1}-I_{R2}=2(V_1-V_2)/(R_1+R_2)\$ so you can get reasonable matching of currents for resistors in the m\$\Omega\$ range. So if your max voltage difference was likely to be 10mV (say) then 10m\$\Omega\$ resistors would give you a matching of 1A.

Also, the current matching due to mismatched interconnect resistance at load is \$I_{R1}/I_{R2}=R_2/R_1\$ so adding 10m\$\Omega\$ to the interconnect in this way should drown out the influence of standard interconnect resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2y8UA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you connect two DC/DC converters in parallel they will probably start to oscillate.

You should look how UPS (uninterruptable power supplies) are made and design something similar.